# Cannot destroy_all users on database because of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have been experiencing problems when trying to destroy_all my users in my database. When I run User.destroy_all I get:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection: Cannot modify association 'Account#hotel_partnerships' because the source reflection class 'Partnership' is associated to 'Hotel' via :has_many.
```

I suspect that the main problem is that in my schema I have an `account`model that `belongs_to` a `user`(the owner of the account) and at the same time the `account has_many users` through its `offices` and `hotels`.

Here's how my associations look like :

```
- Account.rb

    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
      # associations
      has_many :hotel_partnerships, through: :hotels, source: :partnerships, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :office_partnerships, through: :offices, source: :partnerships, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :hotel_users, through: :hotels,source: :users, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :office_users, through: :offices, source: :users, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :hotels, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :offices, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :rooms, through: :hotels, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :tasks, through: :hotels, dependent: :destroy
      belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "admin_user_id", dependent: :destroy

- User.rb

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      ## this line adds auth token to all user on creation
      acts_as_token_authenticatable
      # associations
      belongs_to :account, dependent: :destroy
      has_and_belongs_to_many :hotels
      has_and_belongs_to_many :offices
      has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
      has_one :created_account, class_name: "Account", foreign_key: "admin_user_id", inverse_of: :admin, dependent: :destroy

- Partnership.rb

    class Partnership < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :hotel
      belongs_to :office

- Hotel.rb

    class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
      geocoded_by :full_address
      after_validation :geocode

      has_many :partnerships
      belongs_to :account
      has_and_belongs_to_many :users
      has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :beds, through: :rooms, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms
```

Is it possible to fix this circular association problem ?

Comment: Just basing on the error message, try setting dependent: :destroy for class Hotel for has_many:partnerships (as that seems to be logical anyway).

Comment: @PavelBulanov I just tried but I get the exact same error